# Angularjs directive dependencies (order of execution)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have the following html in which masterdir and innerdir are custom directives:

```
<div master-dir>
    <div inner-dir ng-repeat="x in set"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make the directives execute in the following order (without using $timeout, 'cause it looks ugly to me):

- ng-repeat
- n times innerdir
- masterdir

Background: I want to alter the dom in every directive and the directives kind of depend on each other (the innerdir should alter the dom that ng-repeat produces and the masterdir should alter the dom produced by innerdir)

I've tried it with priority, require and pre/post/compile but I didn't find the right mix. I'm really out of ideas at this point.

Comment: priority only works when directive are on single element. One hack could be to use `$timeout` on the master directive.

Comment: I can make it work by using $timeout (but unfortunately I have to wait for n ms to make sure the entire inner dom was rendered before). It is not hard to imagine that it will take a different amount of time depending on the client that runs the app. So this solution is isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

In https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler they say that, but none chart is there. Anyway, I found that in each directive docs page, in Directive Info section, the priority appears wrote like that (for ng-repeat):

> **ng-repeat:**
>
> Directive Info
>
> This directive creates new scope.
>
> This directive executes at priority level 1000.

I also found the next link that seems to be very helpful. I´m still reading it trying to learn (didn´t know too much about angular priorities). Hope this is helpful for you too.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2447-exploring-directive-controllers-compiling-linking-and-priority-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Thanks, but as  Chandermani already mentioned "priority only works when directive are on single element" which is not the case in my example

Comment: Oh.. Ok. You are right. Anyway I´ve read  in the first link that >A directive is just a function which executes when the compiler encounters it in the DOM.< Then the directives will be executed at the time the DOM element is loaded, then the master-dir should be executed always before, then after that, I supose the ng-repeat and the inner-dir will run. (first will run the higher  priority one between thos two)... is that correct?

Comment: Sure timeout is not the solution O_o !!

Comment: The problem is that masterdir post is called BEFORE the innerdir posts are called which is not what I initially expected

Comment: then maybe you should code it in a different way... :-(      . I think timeouts using angular are breaking angularjs...   When something seems to be tedious in angularjs.. you are doing it not right... (at least my experience)

Comment: This sounds correct somehow. I just don't have a clue where to put dom manipulation other than in a directive